# inserting values as a list in a linux shell environment

Tags: python, django

i am working with the python not too long.Now i am working with django framework.I create a project namely 'speed' and my app is 'car'. I create a model for my app and create database with three attributes.These are name, time and speed.

here is my model,

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Car(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
time = models.DateTimeField()
speed = models.IntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return  ("%s %s %d" ) % (self.name , self.time , self.speed)
```

Now, i create two list for tm and sp and store several values in those list which is given below.

```
  sp = ['20','34','45']
  tm = ['2013-11-02 10:10:02','2013-11-03 10:23:45','2013-11-04 10:34:07']
```

Then i  just want to insert values for name , time , and  speed and store it under a variable just like that.

```
  values = Car(name = "Nexus", time = tm , speed = sp)
```

but when is save it as doing values.save(),then there is error shown which just like that

```
   TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

pleas help me fix this problem.i need to insert the list values.

N.B: i am working in shell environment of linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put sequences into a scalar field.

```
for s, t in zip(sp, tm):
  Car.objects.create(name='Nexus', time=t, speed=s)
```